# How to find partial strings in data

Tags: vba, excel

So I have been working on creating a macro to parse large data sets and I am on the cusp of completion.  I am attempting to analyze dates by month and ignore the year so that I can qualify various if statements to print a string in another column.  Printing the string and everything else is not a problem it's just finding the date.  I don't care so much about the year more just the "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" so that I can determine if it's Q1, Q2, Q3 1H, 2H etc, etc.  The code that I have that I'm attempting to do this with is in the legCounter = 3 block below. (I put two asterisk next to the line that isn't doing what it's supposed to).

```
'Counts legs to narrow structure type
Do
DoEvents
    row_color_tester = row_number

    If tradeTime = Range("B" & (row_color_tester + 1)).Text Or tradeTime = Range("B" & (row_color_tester - 1)).Text Then
        legCounter = legCounter + 1

    End If

    row_number = row_number + 1

Loop Until tradeTime <> Range("B" & (row_color_tester + 1)).Text

'Analyzes individual legs to determine specific structure type
    If legCounter = 2 Then
        Range("Q" & (row_number - legCounter)) = "Spread"
        Rows(row_number - legCounter).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    **ElseIf legCounter = 3 Then
        If StrComp(Range("H" & (row_number - 1)).Text, "Jan", vbTextCompare) > 0 & StrComp(Range("H" & (row_number - 2)).Text, "Feb", vbTextCompare) > 0 & StrComp(Range("H" & (row_number - 3)).Text, "Mar", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then**
            Range("Q" & (row_number - legCounter)) = "Q1"
            Rows(row_number - legCounter).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    ElseIf legCounter = 4 Then
        Range("Q" & (row_number - legCounter)) = legCounter
        Rows(row_number - legCounter).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    ElseIf legCounter = 5 Then
        Range("Q" & (row_number - legCounter)) = legCounter
        Rows(row_number - legCounter).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If

  Loop Until row_number = lastRow
```

The data is stored in Column H and is in this format :

```
16-Mar
16-Feb
16-Jan
```

Comment: It looks to me like you want either the [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or just the Right function to determine the month part of the [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx). The [StrCmp function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s233cfc(v=vs.90).aspx) compares the whole string and returns a sorting position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you want either the [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or just the Right function to determine the month part of the [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx). The [StrCmp function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s233cfc(v=vs.90).aspx) compares the whole string and returns a sorting position.

```
ElseIf legCounter = 3 Then
    If Instr(1, Range("H" & (row_number - 1)).Text, "Jan", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
       Right(Range("H" & (row_number - 2)).Text, 3) = "Feb" Or _
       Range("H" & (row_number - 3)).Text Like "*Mar" Then
        Range("Q" & (row_number - legCounter)) = "Q1"
        Rows(row_number - legCounter).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If
...
```

Those are three text comparison methods. For all four of the quarters, a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) would likely be more appropriate.

```
ElseIf legCounter = 3 Then
    Select Case Right(Range("H" & (row_number - 2)).Text, 3)
      Case "Jan", "Feb", "Mar"
        Range("Q" & (row_number - legCounter)) = "Q1"
        Rows(row_number - legCounter).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
      Case "Apr", "May", "Jun"
        Range("Q" & (row_number - legCounter)) = "Q2"
        Rows(row_number - legCounter).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 '?
      Case "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"
        Range("Q" & (row_number - legCounter)) = "Q3"
        Rows(row_number - legCounter).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 '?
      Case "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
        Range("Q" & (row_number - legCounter)) = "Q4"
        Rows(row_number - legCounter).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 '?
    End Select
...
```

Comment: Hi Jeeped.  I tried the first method of you suggested (If Instr(1,Range etc etc) and it doesn't appear to be working.  The problem I find with the case statements is that it's unable to look backwards because the data is stored in separate cells.  Apologies I maybe should have specified that earlier.  So for example sake 16-Jan is H199 16Feb is H198 and 16-Mar is in H197.  I have the loops set up so that each iteration through the If statements the row_number is the row just after the structure ends.  So in this case with the cells mentioned just above row_counter looking back from H200

Comment: Jeeped I am using the case statement that you provided almost exactly with a small augmentation, however i'm not understanding how it is picking up the 3 rows of the structure.  Could you explain how this is working?  I am new to excel VBA I apologize if the answer is obvious.  All of your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `Select Case ...` is not going to pick up the three row tier structure you have in your worksheet design.

Comment: ...It has...that's why i'm not understanding haha

Comment: Is it possible it's qualifying the second argument and so it's falling into that case?

Comment: Definitely. It really depends on what is in `Range("H" & (row_number - 2)).Text`. That is going to decide the Q*x*. I just don't know how the row above and the row below are ging to adversely affected (if at all).

Answer (score 1):

This small bit will take your range and return the Quarter number.

Format(CDate(Range("H" & (row_number - 1)).Text),"q")

Comment: Maybe even `Format(CDate(Range("H" & (row_number - 1)).Text),"\Qq")`